# How can I apply the datepicker to a textfield in the view?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I’m using a jQuery datepicker in my view .  I get access to the datepicker as long as I’m in the foreach loop like this

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AppointmentNo)
    </td>
}
```

I would like to access the datepicker outside of the foreach loop.  I thought I could do something like this?

```
@DateTime.Now.GetDateTimeFormats()
```

How can I apply the datepicker formatting to an input field outside of the loop?

Here are the files that I've tried adding to the default.cshtml and to the view where I want to use it.

Comment: Can't you use javascript for that? Or manually create the input? (html) http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: I tried this but with no luck:

Date: <input type="text" id="currentDate" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        ("#currentDate").datepicker();
    });
    </script>

Question:  When I installed the jQuery resource files NewGet put the files in sub folders of Script and Content.  Should these files be put directly into the Script folder rather than one of it’s sub folders?

Comment: The content files are fine where they are, if the script files are in a sub directory of script, you can move them to the script folder if you want. Whatever you do you have to make sure you reference the files where they are.

Comment: Have you been able to get the date picker to show up at all?

Comment: it works in other areas of my project like in a table but I want to apply it to a single testbox like this:
Date: <input type="text" id="date" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        ("#date").datepicker();
    });
    </script>  but nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you include the jquery UI file in the master page? Something like this?

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.all.js"></script>`

Comment: I've tried adding these files to my default.cshtml and to the view but still nothing... any ideas?

Comment: I've added the reference files to the default view and tried them on the actual view where I want to use it.  I've added the files to the end of my original post.

Comment: I needed to add the file: jquery.ui.all.js. and was missing the $  from  $("#date").  Thanks for the help!